# How to UPDATE table with SUM() and COUNT() in same table to different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently dont do this for my webpage for displaying data from the table, and it is now taking longer to load the page as more and more data enters the database making the query time consuming. In my head, I am looking to update a table as follows so that I am just querying the table and not running additional arrhythmic on the contents via SELECT functions. I was planning to run something like this in a while loop to cycle all iterations of the `user` variable.

```
UPDATE table
SET total = SUM(sales)
SET orders = COUNT(order)
GROUP by user
WHERE user=$id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it use update value from `left join` (sum + count) table

```
update T T1
  left join (
    select `user`,sum(`sales`) newtotal,count(`order`) neworders
    from T
    group by `user`
  ) T2 on T1.`user` = T2.`user`
set T1.total = T2.newtotal,T1.orders = T2.neworders
```

---

**Test DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE T
    (`user` varchar(4), `sales` int, `order` varchar(7), `total` int, `orders` int)
;

INSERT INTO T
    (`user`, `sales`, `order`, `total`, `orders`)
VALUES
    ('xx01', 100, 'order01', 0, 0),
    ('xx02', 200, 'order02', 0, 0),
    ('xx02', 400, 'order03', 0, 0),
    ('xx03', 300, 'order04', 0, 0),
    ('xx03', 500, 'order05', 0, 0)
;
```

---

**Result:**

```
| user | sales |   order | total | orders |
|------|-------|---------|-------|--------|
| xx01 |   100 | order01 |   100 |      1 |
| xx02 |   200 | order02 |   600 |      2 |
| xx02 |   400 | order03 |   600 |      2 |
| xx03 |   300 | order04 |   800 |      2 |
| xx03 |   500 | order05 |   800 |      2 |
```

---

### [TEST DEMO LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9e8d2/1/0)

Answer (score 3):

You can express this as a single `update` query using `join`:

```
UPDATE t JOIN
       (SELECT user, SUM(sales) as toal, COUNT(order) as orders
        FROM t
        GROUP BY user
       ) tt
       ON t.user = tt.user
    SET t.total = tt.total,
        t.orders = tt.orders;
```

That said, this approach doesn't really make sense.  First, I would question whether or not you really need this approach.  Your SQL is pretty bad, so I'm guessing you haven't tried to optimize the actual query you are using.  If that is of interest, ask *another* question, with sample data, desired results, and the query you are using.

The normal approach to improving performance in this situation is to have a *separate* table with one row per user and a column for each summarized statistic.  You would maintain this table with triggers -- for `update`s, `delete`s, and `insert`s -- so the data is always up-to-date.

Comment: while I believe you both answered the question for me (which I thank you both for) I will definitely be looking in to triggers. It seems to be a much faster and automated alternative.

Comment: ok, researching triggers a bit more... what if a new userID gets added to Table 1, how will the trigger know to insert a new row with the new userID to Table 2?