# How to update a table with data from same table in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL which I want to update

```
NAME   Emp_ID   Points   TotalPoints
ABC    1        50       0
ABC    1        40       0
XYZ    2        20       0
LMN    3        30       0
LMN    3        50       0
XYZ    2        10       0
LMN    3        5        0
```

Please help me to update the same table as shown below by summing up the points

```
NAME   Emp_ID   Points   TotalPoints
ABC    1        50       90
ABC    1        40       90
XYZ    2        20       30
LMN    3        30       85
LMN    3        50       85
XYZ    2        10       30
LMN    3        5        85
```

Comment: It's no different than updating with values from a different table. If you can do that, then this should work as well. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please refer to [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) where the following is written: _'SQL' stands for Structured Query Language, but it's not a programming language, like Python or C#_ So each DBMS may use different SQL syntax and I'm assuming you want SQL that's appropriate for the DBMS you are working with, right? Also, adding DBMS tag attracts people who have experience with that DBMS.

Comment: Does one of these answer your question? [SQL How to Update SUM of column over group in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21871217/90527) 
[How to UPDATE table with SUM() and COUNT() in same table to different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51296435/90527)

Comment: The table is not normalized (if points are not unique, then there is no candidate key; `NAME` depends on `Emp_ID` and is repeated, as does `TotalPoints` (if there were a candidate key, this would violate 2NF)), and is thus prone to data integrity issues. The table should first be normalized into additional tables. After that, the total points can (e.g.) be calculated in a view or updated via triggers; "[How best to recalculate group by values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6979198/90527)" addresses this.

Answer (score 2):

I only tried the below SQL on Oracle 18c database, but I believe it is fairly standard SQL and so should work with all the major DBMS

```sql
update EMPS E1
   set E1.TOTAL_POINTS = (select sum(E2.POINTS)
                            from EMPS E2
                           where E2.EMP_ID = E1.EMP_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, here is the [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bHLuPktVNQ6E41cBXDefSW/1). This code work for MySQL 8.0, SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

```
select
    name,
    emp_id,
    points,
    sum(points) over (partition by emp_id) as total_points
from yourTable
order by
    name
```

Comment: I think the OP want to update the column, not return data, but it's not clear. Sorry about your edit, earlier -- I did mine at the same time (think yours was the same?) but since I have enough reputation mine went through instantly and yours was rejected automatically as soon as a conflicting edit was made

Comment: Works with MySQL and Postgres? Why, I never. Well, I retract my comment.